# Add various multiboot options just like WinPE by Strelec on flash drive

Tags: usb-drive, multiboot

So I've been wanting to put a windows 10 ISO on my flash drive, but I have WinPe by strelec already on it. I don't know how I can a windows installer on top of it and I don't even know if that's even possible at all... Please send help I'm a newbie when it comes to software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it is not possible to have multiple bootable OSes if something is already present, (at least to the extent of my knowledge) but if you'd like to dualboot on a clean USB drive, (erase your existing one, even) there exist several tools that can do that, such as [Easyboot](http://www.ezbsystems.com/easyboot/download.htm), syslinux, or even grub4dos. Some other helpful resources can also be found at [Reboot.pro](http://reboot.pro/). However, if you are currently running Windows, I recommend [WinSetupFromUSB](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/) as an easy way to get a multiboot USB drive going.

Comment: Bummer, but if it isn't possible then it's fine.The main idea was to add a windows installer options together with the WinPe but if it isn't possible I'll just give up and buy another flash drive

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible just use ventoy and You can have multiple ISO's in the same usb, boot from USB and choose the want to boot, https: //www.ventoy.net/